# Without calling parents class constructor,it is possible to call direct child class constructor in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, parent-child

I have a parents class whose name 'parents'  and child class whose name 'child' which is extends parent class. if child class and parents class both having same argument but different behaviour constructor then if i am create child class objcet it will automatically call parents class constructor which i don't want.how it is possible.

Ex.

```
    class parents
    {
      parents()
      {
      
     System.out.println("hello, i am 
          parents class constructor");
      }
    }

    class child extends parents
    {
      child()
      {
     System.out.println("hello, i am 
  child class constructor");
      }
    }

    class main
    {
      public static void 
   main(String[] args)
      { 
        child c = new child();
      }
    }
```

Now here,

Output is.....

```
    hello, i am  parents class constructor
    hello, i am  child class constructor
```

But i want only...

```
    hello, i am child class constructor
```

Means only child class constructor is run not parent class.

How it is possible...

Comment: No, it's not possible in standard Java. And with good reason. If you don't want the child to behave like the parent class, then it shouldn't be a parent class. It should be an instance variable or not even present at all.

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider accepting it. It helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the constructor of a class is called, the constructors of its parent class are implicitly invoked as well.

The reasoning, as pointed in the comment by @SilvioMayolo, is that

> "If you don't want the child to behave like the parent class, then it shouldn't be a parent class."

Conceptually, **it is a child class is because the child inherits some properties or functionalities from its parent**. As in your example, if you don't want `"hello, i am parent class constructor"` to be printed when the child constructor is called, you actually do not need the parent class of the child to actually be its parent.

Therefore, what functionality you want to achieve is not possible in Java because it is an implicit feature of the language.